# Implement custom authorized action wicket

Tags: wicket

I want to make authentication in my web app, when some actions occured on page. For example user click button "add to cart" and if he not yet authenticated, then signIn page displayed. After signIn it returns back to previos page. 
What i can use in wicket to implement this?

P.S. On product page i have also link "buy now", which navigate to Buy page with @AuthorizeInstantiation("USER") annotation. This link work just fine.

I think MetaDataRoleAuthorizationStrategy can be used to make the same on "add to cart". But available actions is ENABLE and RENDER only. I can add my own Action to component, but how can i associate Action with onClick() method of component?

---Edited---

Don't know where to write, so i edit the post. I try Christoph Leiter's solution:

```
add(link = new AjaxFallbackLink("add2cart") {
 @Override
  public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
   if (!CynephoneSession.get().isSignedIn()) {
    throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(SignIn.class);
   }
   user.addItem(item.copy());
   target.add(cartPanel);
  }
});
```

but after i clicked this link somehow i see ajax response with updated cartPanel in firefox. I mean it show me page with source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajax-response><component id="cart2" ><![CDATA[<div class="cart" wicket:id="cart" id="cart2">
<span wicket:id="total">11 800</span> <img src="./resource/top.Top/img/rouble-ver-1346040298957.gif"/><br/>
<img src="./resource/top.Top/img/good-ver-1346040298926.gif"/>х<span wicket:id="quantity">2</span>
</div>]]></component></ajax-response>
```

Don't understand how it pass the Exception...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert with the authroles module, so I'm not sure whether it's possible to add another Action to accomplish what you want. I would just use something like that:

```
new AjaxLink<Product>("addToCart", product) {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        if (!AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession.get().isSignedIn()) {
            // code to remember product to add to cart in session
            throw new RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException(LoginPage.class);
        }
        // continue normally
    }
};
```

In your `LoginPage`/`Session` you should check if there's a product in the session that should be added to the cart when the user is authenticated successfully. Then call `continueToOriginalDestination` so that Wicket displays the previous page (or `setResponsePage(CartPage.class)`).

There may be a better way than to do this "manually", but this should work.

Comment: Thank you! I don't look into wicket exceptions before. Now i see it's another way to control execution flow.

Comment: I try this and strange result occurs. I add it to head.

Comment: Can you try stepping through with a debugger to see what exactly is going on? If the exception is thrown I don't see how this code could get executed.

Comment: I run debug now. Looks like wicket so smart that continueToOriginalDestination moves it to previos page and clicked button.

Comment: it's good new for me - not need to remember produst. I'll try to learn more how this Exception works.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at class SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy. This class already checks if the user is signed  when he requests for a specific page class and it automatically redirects him to login page if he is not signed in.
I would also use PageParameters to pass CartPage the id of the product we must add to the cart. In this way you can avoid to store the selected product into session and retrieve it after user has successfully signed in.

Comment: Thank you! But i have cartPanel and it's already instantiated on my page. So if user click "add to cart" and he is already authenticated, then just my cart label updated wia ajax. Can i use strategies in that case?

Comment: No, I thought your cart was handled in a page and not in a panel. SimplePageAuthorizationStrategy can only work with pages.